# new object each time mutation happens in go?

Tags: go

I have this go code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type User struct {
    Name string
    Sex string
}

func main() {
    u := &User{Name: "Leto", Sex: "Male"}
    fmt.Printf("main() address: %p %p\n", &u, &u.Name)
    Modify(u)
    Modify(u)
    Modify2(u)
    Modify2(u)
}

func Modify(u *User) {
    u.Name = "Paul11"
    fmt.Printf("Modify() address: %p %p\n", &u, &u.Name)
}

func Modify2(u *User) {
    u.Name = "Leto"
    fmt.Printf("Modify() address: %p %p\n", &u, &u.Name)
}
```

The output is

```
main() address: 0x1040a120 0x10434120
Modify() address: 0x1040a130 0x10434120
Modify() address: 0x1040a138 0x10434120
Modify() address: 0x1040a140 0x10434120
Modify() address: 0x1040a148 0x10434120
```

I wonder 
1. why the address of the object after mutation is different. 
2. why the first takes 16 bytes, and afterwards it is only 8 bytes. 
3. why the mutated field is still using the same memory address.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The methods are printing the address of the receiver argument `u`, a `**User`.

Print `u` instead of `&u` and you will observe that the address remains the same. A new `User` value is not created on every mutation.

```
func Modify(u *User) {
  u.Name = "Paul11"
  fmt.Printf("Modify() address: %p %p\n", u, &u.Name)
}

func Modify2(u *User) {
   u.Name = "Leto"
   fmt.Printf("Modify() address: %p %p\n", u, &u.Name)
}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/7ywy2jVKHk)